# How to declare a two-dimensional templated class-type vector?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, constructor

I am testing my knowledge of generics in C++. Although I am getting a grasp of it, I still need to tighten up a few ends on my knowledge of the subject. Currently, I'm having a problem with using a templated class constructor. I'm getting an undefined reference error. Since I know that the compiler needs to have access to the entire template definition in order to compile code for each instantiation of the template, I kept the definition of the constructor in the .h file as shown below:

```
  #ifndef CLASS1_H
  #define CLASS1_H

  #include <vector>
  #include <string>
  using namespace std;

  template <class T, int N>
  class Class1{
  public:

  Class1(string inName, int capacity);

  private:
   string m_name;
   int m_capacity;
  };

  template <class T, int N>
  Class1<T, N>::Class1(string inName, int capacity) {
    m_name = inName;
    m_capacity = capacity;
  }

  #endif
```

This I declared correctly as far as I know. The following class, Class2.cpp,  uses the constructor from Class1 in it's constructor parameter:

```
 #include "Class2.h"

 using namespace std;

 Class2::Class2(vector< Class1 <ClassPI, 3141> > ident) { 
   m_ident = ident;
 }
```

I tried declaring "template class Class1< ClassPI, 3141 > underCode" at the bottom of "Class2.cpp" but it didn't work (as I have already implemented the Class2 constructor(?)). Here is the header file for Class2:

```
 #ifndef CLASS2_H
 #define CLASS2_H

 #include "Class1.h"
 #include "ClassPI.h"

 class Class2 {
 public:
   Class2(vector< Class1<ClassPI, 3141> > ident);


 private:
   vector< Class1<ClassPI, 3141> > m_ident;
 };

 #endif
```

Finally, here is the main class:

```
 #include "Class2.h"
 #include "Class1.h"
 #include "ClassPI.h"
 #include <vector>

 using namespace std;

 int main() {

 vector< Class1<ClassPI, 159> > vect;

 Class2 class2 ( vect );

 }
```

I get the following error message when I compile the code:

```
 main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
 main.cpp:12: error: no matching function for call to 
 ‘Class2::Class2(std::vector<Class1<ClassPI, 234>, std::allocator<Class1<ClassPI, 234> > >&)’
 Class2.h:9: note: candidates are: Class2::Class2(std::vector<Class1<ClassPI, 3141>, std::allocator<Class1<ClassPI, 3141> > >)
 Class2.h:7: note:                 Class2::Class2(const Class2&)
 make: *** [main] Error 1
```

I have already made the constructor definition as seen above. That's the only reason why I think I'm getting this error message, but apparently it not the correct reason. What else am I missing?

P.s.:
ClassPI.h:

```
#ifndef CLASSPI_H
#define CLASSPI_H

#include "ClassPI.h"

using namespace std;

class ClassPI
{
 public:

 ClassPI();
};

#endif
```

ClassPI.cpp:

```
 #include"ClassPI.h"
 using namespace std;

 ClassPI::ClassPI(){}
```

Class3.h

```
 #ifndef CLASS3_H
 #define CLASS3_H

 using namespace std;

 template <class T, int N>
 class Class3 {
 public:
   Class3(); 
 };
```

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate, which means I'm doing something different. May we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: Why did you put "undefined reference to" in the title, when the actual error message is `error: no matching function for call to`...

Comment: anyway, change `159` to `3141` or vice versa

Comment: @M.M I got the "undefined reference to" error initially, but I edited the original post, but in the process of editing my post for correctness, I got a different error, and I forgot to change the title. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I changed the const argument from the original value (3141) to 159 in the main file. So I went back and changed it to:

```
vector< Class1<ClassPI, 3141> > vect;
```

and the code ran and compiled successfully.